# Can I add Facebook like button without use API id?

Tags: php, facebook-like

I want to add a facebook like button on my site, but I need to create an API id.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
2. fill in the details in the form,  click get code
3. paste into your site.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you search google for "I want to add a facebook like button on my site, but I neet create an API id." your first hit will be your answer.

Comment: we could all just say,  why dont you google for the answer,  but what help would that be?

Comment: To teach people to help themselves.
"Give a man a fish..."

Comment: it so happens that this very query of his question links to the very page than in the very first paragraph has example code to show him how to do what he inquires about.